# SSAS named set with hard codded members

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap-cube, msbi

I am trying to create a common named set with fixed members so it can be used in multiple calculated members. But for some reason, it's failing. I am new to MDX scripting. Let me know if there is an issue here.

```
Aggregate({[TT Collection].[TT Type].&[A]
,[TT Collection].[TT Type].&[O]
,[TT Collection].[TT Type].&[I]
,[TT Collection].[TT Type].&[J]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create the set before Aggregating does it work?

```
WITH
SET [MYSET] AS
    {[TT Collection].[TT Type].&[A]
    ,[TT Collection].[TT Type].&[O]
    ,[TT Collection].[TT Type].&[I]
    ,[TT Collection].[TT Type].&[J]}
MEMBER [SOMEdim].[SOMEhier].X AS
    AGGREGATE([MYSET])
...
...
```

Comment: @whythq Thank you for the answer. I too tried like this after some research and it worked.